# Should an assets folder be added for fonts in an Android Project? Why?

Tags: android, font-awesome, directory-structure

So, I have an android project and have a `fonts` folder under the default resources directory. I even have fonts in there that are being used throughout the app.

I'm looking into adding Font Awesome to my app, however, many of the tutorials online say to create an "assets" folder and a fonts folder within that.

Is there a reason to do this as opposed to putting the fonts directory under the default resource directory?

Would it still be valid if I simply continued using the `fonts` folder I already have under  the default `res`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font resources were added in Android 8.0, and `appcompat` supports them on older devices. Tutorials that are older than ~15 months will have been written before font resources existed, and the primary way of using fonts previously involved `assets/`.

> Would it still be valid if I simply continued using the fonts folder I already have under the default res?

Probably. It is conceivable that the Font Awesome fonts foil the font resource system somehow (perhaps they are *too* awesome), but I haven't heard of people having that sort of problem.

Comment: Hmm... what about for projects like mine that are writing app to support from APIs 15 (android 4.03) to API 27. Should this still work for me?

Comment: @JDoe: If you are using `appcompat` (`AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`, etc.), then yes. It is how your current font resources are working.